# How to PRINT(HardCopy), When User click on Save button All Data with user name and 24 HOURS timing detail PRINTOUT

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

```
$uder= getAnyData($select = '*', 'tblname', "id=$id");
$obj1=$uder[0];
$obj2=$uder[1];
$obj3=$uder[2];
```

//---- Get value and for retrieve a value create three Variable

```
if($obj1 !="")
{
    if($obj1['type']=="1")
    {
        echo "value is already Primary";
        // Display Primary Value And All data of user's timing
    }
    else if($obj1['type']=="2")
    {
        echo "value is already secondary";
        // Display secondary Value And All data of user's timing
    }
    else
    {
        echo "value is already prefferd";
        // Display prefferd Value And All data of user's timing
    }
}
```

//--- Store DATA in $obj1

```
  if($obj2 !="")
    {
        if($obj2['type']=="1")
        {
            echo "value already Primary";
            // Display Primary Value And All data of user's timing
        }
        else if($obj2['type']=="2")
        {
            echo "value is already secondary";
            // Display secondary Value And All data of user's timing
        }
        else
        {
            echo "value is already prefferd";
            // Display prefferd Value And All data of user's timing
        }
    }
```

//-- Store all Data in $obj2

```
if($obj3 !="")
    {
        if($obj3['type']=="1")
        {
            echo "value already Primary";
            // Display primary Value And All data of user's timing
        }
        else if($obj3['type']=="2")
        {
            echo "value is already secondary"
            // Display secondary Value And All data of user's timing
        }
        else
        {
            echo "value is already prefferd";
            // Display prefferd Value And All data of user's timing
        }
    }
```

//--- After Click on Save button all PRIMARY,SECONDARY and PREFFRD Time will display in PRINT (ctrl+P) with all Content.

Comment: I don't understand how *any* of the code shown relates to wanting to print something, but in any case, print where? The end user's printer, or a printer that is accessible from your web server?

Comment: I want to Print a User's Entry and Exit time detail with Mon-Sat.

Comment: here only i store value of them timing in OBJ for example PT(Part Time),Full-Time(FT) or Other, using that details able to retrieve all data with entry and exit time of user's and want that result will printout after click on save button.

Comment: Did you even read my comment? Again, print *where*? If you want it to print to a printer connected to the user's PC then all this PHP is irrelevant. If you want it to print to a printer connected to your webserver then the "javascript" and "ajax" tags are irrelevant.

Comment: I want it to print connected with my web server Printer.